# sencha run native throws an error

Tags: sencha-touch, osx-mavericks

I am fairly new to sencha development.  I have installed JDK, Ant, Compass, Sencha Cmd, Sencha SDK, XCode, ios-simulator and Cordova. and I believe that I have all the paths properly set.

I generated an app (Sample01) using sencha cmd.  I initialized cordova using "sencha cordova init com.snehca.Sample01 Sample01".  If I build using "sencha app build native" (without run option), the app compiles successfully.

However, if I execute "sencha app build -run native", it throws error as follows:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/__core.files
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/__manifest
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/__class.metadata
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/__class.metadata
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/__class.metadata
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/__class.metadata
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/build/temp/native/Sample01/__override.files
[INF] Appending content to /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/bootstrap.json
[INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www/app.js
[INF] merging resources into /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www/resources
[INF] merging resources into /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www
[INF] merged 0 resources into /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
[INF] Copying page resources to /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www
[INF] Writing content to /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www/app.json
[INF] Writing content to /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to /Sencha/Projects/Sample01/cordova/www/index.html
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Sencha/Projects/Sample01/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:427: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Sencha/Projects/Sample01/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:108: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/jpulakhandam/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.0.0.160/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:608: shellscript returned: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my env the problem was fixed updating the Android SDK Build Tools, before update I was getting the same error posted and my Android SDK Build Tools rev. was 19.0.3 then I updated to Android SDK Build Tools rev 20 and the problem was fixed.